# Search Query Only Returning Part of Results I Need

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, enterprise-search

I have a search center hooked up to a records center. The records in the RC are tagged as one of two content types: `Controlled or Uncontrolled`.

I've setup a search query that looks like this:

```
{searchboxquery} SPContentType=uncontrolled
```

Problem is it only returns 8 results, and I know from looking through the records center that there should be 58.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ContentType=Uncontrolled` also, check for permissions and duplicate trimming.